# Add Apache Ignite cache backup configuration after cache was created

Tags: caching, cluster-computing, ignite

I've created an partitioned persistent Ignite cache with SQL DDL. By default the backup setting is "0", now I want to add backup with size "2" per node (we have 3 nodes). In the ignite server nodes I edited the configuration xml file to look like this:

```
<bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">

        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
                <list>
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                        .
                        .
                        </bean>
                        .
                        .
                        
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                                <property name="name" value="ourCache"/>
                                <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                                <property name="backups" value="2"/>
                                <property name="groupName" value="grp" />
                                <property name="partitionLossPolicy" value="READ_ONLY_SAFE"/>
                        </bean>
                </list>
        </property>
```

Unfortunately in the ignite visior when I invoke to see the configuration I see that the  "Affinity Backups" is still 0. I've checked the "cache -a" statistics where you can usually see the backup records per node - still 0.

How can I add backups for existing caches? The baseline is used in production and there are >100M records already.

Answer (score 1):

The only way of changing backup factor or most of the other cache configuration properties is to create new cache, copy over all data to it from the old cache (if needed) and destroy the old cache.

Comment: I wonder what will happen if we decide to expand the baseline form 3 to 5 nodes. Then the backup factor should be expanded also. I can dynamically add new nods in the baseline but I can not change the cache config and cache needs to be moved/destroyed?

Comment: I don't think that you need to expand your backup factor in case of scaling up. Backup factors mean that your data can survive a particular amount of nodes leaving a cluster. If your aim is to store data everywhere then you could consider [replicated](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-modes#replicated-mode) cache mode. Is that what you're looking for? @cyber_terminator

Comment: I would like to have more resilience and still to have the performance of the partitioned cache mode. For this setup it is recommended to have back copies N-1 where N is the number of the nodes, giving the possibility for the cluster to be extended (changing N) I was thinking that is natural to be able to extend the number of back-up copies. To answer you question - Unfortunately I'm not looking for replicated mode.